# Python3 input with different value types

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ")
```

Python3 returns that ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). What can I do to fix that?

Comment: `string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ").split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` method returns a **single string value** unless you split it into parts with `split()`(by default splits where *spaces* are).

```
>>> string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ")
Enter a word and an integer: test 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>>> string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ").split()
Enter a word and an integer: test 5
>>> string
'test'
>>> integer
'5'
```

Comment: yes because it was split from a string. It is needed to be cast to an integer if needed as an integer and this was totally out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack any iterable into variables.

A string is a variable, so for instance, you could do:

```
a,b = 'yo'
```

which gives `a = 'y'` and `b = 'o'`.

If you wish to unpack two "words", you must split your string on spaces to obtain a list of the two words.

I.e.

```
'hello user'.split()
```

Gives `['hello', 'user']`.

You can then unpack this list into two variables.

This is what you want, but splitting the string returned from `input()`.

I.e.

```
string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ").split()
```

Is what you are looking for.

Oh, and if you want the `integer` variable to actually be an integer, you should convert it to one after:

```
integer = int(integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, I think that what may sound right is to impose a given type to the user:

```py
def typed_inputs(text, *types):
    user_input = input(text).split()
    return tuple(t(v) for t, v in zip(*types, user_input))
```

Which can be used as follows:

```py
>>> types = (int, float, str)
>>> message = f"Input the following types {types} :"
>>> print(typed_inputs(message, types))
Input the following types (<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>) : 1 2.1 test
(1, 2.3, 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following would work but both will be strings.

```
string, integer = input("Enter a word and an integer: ").split()
```

You need to have something like this.

```
string_val, integer_val = raw_input("String"), int(raw_input("Integer"))
```

It would fail if user doesn't enter an int. 
You might wanna user Try catch and inform the user.